# Supertest возвращает 404 ошибку при запросе на роут с параметром

Tags: javascript, node.js, jest

Такой роут точно есть и через постман работает

Код теста

```
describe('Test search user', () => {
    let userData: IUserData[] = [
            {nickname: 'test', name: 'Test', phone: '+380666876892', sessionCode: '12345678'},
            {nickname: 'user', name: 'Test2', phone: '+380506564229', sessionCode: '87654321'}
        ];

    beforeAll(async done => {
        await resetDB();

        //create data
        await Promise.all(userData.map(async d => {
            const user = await UserRepository.create(d);
            return user._id;
        }));

        done();
    });

    jest.setTimeout(30000);

    it('Test success user search', async done => {
        const token = await jwt.sign({
            session: userData[0].sessionCode,
            expires: Date.now() + 300000
        }, <string>process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        //make api call
        st(app)
            .get(`/users/${userData[1].nickname}`)
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            .expect(200)
            .expect(res => {
                expect(res.body).toMatchObject({
                    message: 'User was found',
                    user: userData[1]
                })
            })
            .end(done);
    });

    it('Test not authorized user search', async done => {
        st(app)
            .get(`/users/${userData[1].nickname}`)
            .expect(401)
            .end(done);
    });

    it('Test search of not exists user', async done => {
        const token = await jwt.sign({
            session: userData[0].sessionCode,
            expires: Date.now() + 300000
        }, <string>process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        st(app)
            .get('/users/notFound')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            .expect(200)
            .expect({
                message: 'User with this nickname are not exists',
                user: null
            })
            .end(done);
    });
});
```

Регистрация роута

```
usersRouter.get('/:nickname', UsersController.getUser);
rootRouter.use('/users', UsersRoutes);
```

Код контроллера

```
class UsersController{
    async getUser(req: IGetUserRequest, res: Response){
        const nickname = req.params.nickname,
            user = await UsersRepository.getByNick(nickname);

        if(!user) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'User with this nickname are not exists',
                user: null
            });
        }
        else{
            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'User was found',
                user
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка

> Error: expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"

Comment: мне кажется, что может быть не запущен app. можно прописать роут `test` возвращающий что-то простое, и, для подтверждения в рамках теста, можно выполнить запрос к нему. ну и, в общем, не понятно какой именно тест сваливается

Comment: падают только тесты, которые идут с токеном, я проверил, supertest просто не матчит этот путь ни с каким роутом и мой дефолтный обработчик возвращает 404. Она падает только если тестирую роут с параметром, уже написал кучу тестов для других роутов и всё работает

Comment: слушай, меня вот что ещё смущает: у тебя есть класс UsersController и у экземпляра этого класса есть метод getUser, а в роут у тебя передаётся `usersRouter.get('/:nickname', UsersController.getUser)`. метод не статический, получается передаётся undefined?

Comment: я экспортирую экземпляр контроллера вместо использования статических методов